# Android How to SET List<String> in listview

Tags: java, android, shell

Please here is my code but it's not working as well and i am not sure where is problem ! would any can help ! i am trying with this !

```
List<String> array= new ArrayList<String>();
    array.add("Some Text");
    array.add("Some Text");
    array.add("Some Text");

    ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViews);
    ArrayAdapter<String> mHistory = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, array);
    listView.setAdapter(mHistory);
```

Comment: Your question is too poorly worded. Please add the logcat stack trace.

Comment: do one thing, change  android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2 to android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

Comment: Hello,Anoopss Golden  Thanks for your great help ! i am new with android !

Comment: and your solutions working as well ! lot of thanks for your help !

Comment: @user1609904 welcome, dont forget to give feedback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the `simple_expandable_list_item_2` layout. You should use the `simple_list_item_1` instead.

```
ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViews);
    ArrayAdapter<String> mHistory = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array)
    listView.setAdapter(mHistory);
```

Comment: sorry, I thought android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2 is just a resource id, how could you know he should use another resource? and how could you know he has a resource named: android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1? (forgive me if this question is silly:))

Comment: @lzprgmr the `android.R.*` resources are part of Android, not your app so every Android device / app can use these.